# Can I stop OSX from creating .DS_Store / ._blah files everywhere on NTFS?

Tags: macos, ntfs

These files really get on my nerves. Can I make OSX not create them somehow? (._blah are only created on NTFS external disk, .DS_Store are created everywhere)

Answer (score 5):

Use [BlueHarvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest4/) to prevent these files from being created.

[image]

---

Remember that [._ files might contain useful information](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/FilesAndFinder.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002285-108704-BCIIICII).

Comment: Upvoted for correctness and the name of the program :)