# Make Mac OS not add rubbish files everywhere

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compressing folders on a mac, without the .DS_Store](https://superuser.com/questions/198569/compressing-folders-on-a-mac-without-the-ds-store)

My OS puts random files and folders (like .DS_Store or __MACOSX) everywhere. This is embarrassing when I send projects to my clients who complain about multiple junk files in the .zip. How do I make Mac OS X stop doing that?

Comment: Remind your clients that Windows users frequently add `Thumbs.db` files to their archives.

Comment: [And this one](http://superuser.com/questions/140484/can-i-stop-osx-from-creating-ds-store-blah-files-everywhere-on-ntfs).

Comment: It is not clear what you're complaining about. Do you care about those files (`.DS_Store` primarily) existing on your own disk, or just in the zip files you send your client?